# docx->zip->xml на PHP вместо XML приходит текст

Tags: php, ms-word, docx

При вызове функции даю на вход путь к файлу docx. Открываю как архив ZIP далее хочу достать содержимое `word/document.xml` в чистом виде со всеми тегами. Однако на экране вижу только текст без тегов. Подскажите в каком моменте он съедает теги XML?

```
function extractxml($filename) {
  $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
      if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
          $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
        var_dump($text);
      }
      $zip->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: запиши в текстовый файл

Comment: $file = 'xml.txt'; file_put_contents($file, $text, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: В моменте построения DOM на клиенте(т.е. у вас в браузере).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вот чёрт, это же так элементарно было)